# How can I set Powershell check box to False after button click

Tags: powershell, checkbox

I am creating a Powershell GUI, I have a Checkbox that will force the user to change password on logon. I have the textbox for the password set to clear and it works fine, but I cannot find a way to uncheck the Box programmatically. I have tried  $CheckBoxRLO.Checked -eq $true After the code to reset the password but the box stays checked.

Answer (score 1):

`$CheckBoxRLO.Checked = $false` worked, I swear I tried it as well but I must have done 20 things besides it. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign it value false. What you're right now doing is using binary operator -eq, it compares two values (left hand, right hand) and either returns false or true, this is not what you want to do.

Try

```
$CheckBoxRLO.Checked = $false
```